# CMake error installing qiskit-aer from source

Tags: cmake, pip, ubuntu-20.04, ninja, qiskit

I am trying to install Qiskit from source using the instructions [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/getting_started.html) (Select the "Install from source" tab). I am installing on 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and have just updated all packages.

I am getting the errors shown below, which might be related to CMake or ninja. Ninja is installed, but when I run ninja I get this message:

```
> ninja
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory
```

I am not sure if this is relevant or not.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

```
>    pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit-aer
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.6 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.9.0) (2.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: qiskit-terra>=0.17.0 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit-terra (from qiskit-aer=>
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.3 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.9.0) (1.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-aer==0.9.0) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=2.6 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-terra>=0.17.0->qiskit->
Requirement already satisfied: retworkx>=0.9.0 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-terra>=0.17.0->qiskit->
Requirement already satisfied: ply>=3.10 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-terra>=0.17.0->qiskit-aer==0>
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-terra>=0.17.0->qiskit-aer==0>
Requirement already satisfied: sympy>=1.3 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-terra>=0.17.0->qiskit-aer==>
Requirement already satisfied: dill>=0.3 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-terra>=0.17.0->qiskit-aer==0>
Requirement already satisfied: fastjsonschema>=2.10 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-terra>=0.17.0->qi>
Requirement already satisfied: python-constraint>=1.4 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-terra>=0.17.0->>
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.0 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-terra>=0.17.0->>
Requirement already satisfied: symengine>0.7 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from qiskit-terra>=0.17.0->qiskit-ae>
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->qiskit-terra>=>
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->qiskit-terra>=0.1>
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->qiskit-terra>=0.>
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jsonschema>=2.6->qiskit-te>
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sympy>=1.3->qiskit-terra>=0.17.0>
Installing collected packages: qiskit-aer
  Attempting uninstall: qiskit-aer
    Found existing installation: qiskit-aer 0.9.0
    Uninstalling qiskit-aer-0.9.0:
      Successfully uninstalled qiskit-aer-0.9.0
  Running setup.py develop for qiskit-aer
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/bin/python3.9 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/john/anaconda3>
         cwd: /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit-aer/
    Complete output (77 lines):
    Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
      Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
      CMake.

      Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
      CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit-aer/_cmake_test_compile/build
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (project):
      Running

       '/tmp/pip-build-env-v00vgfai/overlay/bin/ninja' '--version'

      failed with:

       No such file or directory


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit-aer/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.9/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-nhehkrf9/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 582, in setup
        env = cmkr.configure(cmake_args,
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-nhehkrf9/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 229, in configure
        raise SKBuildError(
    An error occurred while configuring with CMake.
      Command:
        /tmp/pip-build-env-nhehkrf9/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-p>
      Source directory:
        /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit-aer
      Working directory:
        /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit-aer/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.9/cmake-build
    Please see CMake's output for more information.


    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Trying "Ninja" generator
    --------------------------------
    ---------------------------
    ----------------------
    -----------------
    ------------
    -------
    -- 
    -- 
    -------
    ------------
    -----------------
----------------------
    ---------------------------
    --------------------------------
    -- Trying "Ninja" generator - success
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Configuring Project
      Working directory:
        /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit-aer/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.9/cmake-build
      Command:
        /tmp/pip-build-env-nhehkrf9/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-p>

    Traceback (most recent call last):

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of qiskit-aer
  Moving to /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit-aer.egg-link
   from /tmp/pip-uninstall-vno4ffn6/qiskit-aer.egg-link
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/john/anaconda3/envs/QiskitDevenv/bin/python3.9 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.ar>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error msg `ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory`  is not relevant, and is due to the file build.niinja not existing..
The pb is rather a cmake error when building (running setup.py) Aer package.

- Try to downgrade python to version 3.8 or even 3.7 (I remember a similar problem when installing from WSL Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.9. Downgrading to Python 3.8 solved it)
- Try using the latest stable version of qiskit-aer (git checkout tags/0.8.2)

Comment: @Patrick_Mensac I downgraded to Python 3.8 and installed some more libraries (nlohmann-json3-dev,  libspdlog-dev, libmuparserx-dev and libpthread-stubs0-dev)

The problem is now CMake can't find libpthreads.so  (no 's' at the end of thread):
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads. 
I have libpthread.so. I tried linking libpthreads.so to libpthread.so and running ldconfig a few times, but it doesn't recognise the new library (ldconfig -p | grep libpthread only finds libpthread.so, not the libpthreads.so)

Comment: @john, have you tried installing qiskit using "pip install qiskit" ?  do you get the same error ?  the "build-essential" package should set the compiler and needed tools to install from source.  I guess you remove the _sk_build directory under qiskit-aer before trying a new aer installation.  Patrick

Comment: I can run "pip install qiskit", but I really want to build from the latest source that I have obtained using "git pull". I have found a tolerable workaround: building everything under Fedora 33 using a Singularity container. I chose Fedora 33 because I successfully built Qiskit from source on another machine running Fedora 33. Thanks for you help.